# ".OFF" descriptions

Tags: graphics, 3d, raytracing, object-files

I'd like to make a scene that uses meshes and primitives (such as spheres, cylinders, boxes, etc). I was wondering if there are any recommendations with regard to where I can go to find .off files that describes complex meshes, such as mountains, rocks, trees, animals, etc.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are plenty of sites that share/sell models, like **[turbosquid](http://www.turbosquid.com/Search/Index.cfm?FuseAction=ProcessSmartSearch&intStartRow=1&intMediaType=-1&istSearchKey=tree)**.
You can use **[Blender](http://www.blender.org/download/get-blender/)** to **import** many 3d formats(3ds,obj,lwo,ma,etc.) and **export** your mesh(es) to .off format.

[image: Blender export menu]

.obj is highlighted, but you can see **DEC Object File Format (*.off)** on the list.